# jQuery UI sorting is not working in ajax content load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I am doing a sorting ,here i am facing some problem like sorting is not working in the ajax part but page load it is coming fine.
I have tried it some other way its working  ,but i have to write that sorting code twice ,instead of doing one ajax call .
How can I make it for the page load as well as ajax call using one function only .
below is my code

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () { //for ajax call
        $("#sortable-1").sortable({opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update: function () {
                var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();//   var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                //  alert(order);
                $.post("ajax-upload-picture.php?action=sorting", {"order": order}, function (theResponse) {

                });

            }

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () { //for page loading 
        $("#sortable-1").sortable({opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update: function () {
                var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();//   var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                //  alert(order);
                $.post("ajax-upload-picture.php?action=sorting", {"order": order}, function (theResponse) {

                });

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

I want it to work in one ajax call

Comment: create a function and call from doc.ready?

Comment: I am not getting you .Is there any solution of my problem ?
I  want to do it in one sortable function. @Bhavik Patel

Comment: you have to re-write the code twice in `doc.ready` and `doc.ajaxsuccess` ? If that's the case, why not just create a function having the sortable code and make a call from `doc.ready` and `doc.ajaxsuccess` ?

Comment: Ok  I  am trying ..